# efficient way to check parked domains?

Tags: dns

I am writing a script that checks if given domain is parked or not. so far, I have this solution:

- add couple of characters at the end of the url.
- if url redirects to another page and

  - returns 302 http status code then it is parked domain.
  - returns other than 302 then it is normal domain.
- but some normal domains also return 302.

so any suggestions are greatly appreciated.

Comment: Can you provide a clearer definition of "parked". I looked at the wikipedia entry, and it seems like there could be many possible behaviors for what is a high-level characterization.

Comment: In case you're interested in a CLI tool that accomplishes this: https://github.com/gr3atest/excludeparked

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's not as simple as that. A 302 response just means content is temporarily at a different location. This can happen on a normal website and it doesn't always happen on a parked site.

I worked at an ISP with over 20,000 parked domains and we didn't use 302's on any of them.

I don't think you'll find a 100% solution for this. Even if you checked the page for phrases such as "Buy This Domain" and "This Domain May Be For Sale" you won't know for sure.